# Why does the U.S. not recognize North Korea as a nation?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, north-korea

The U.S. officially recognizes only the government of South Korea and not the government of North Korea. I am trying to understand why this is because the U.S. has recognized many other dictatorships including the governments of Saddam Hussein and the government of Bashar Al Assad. 
Historically we also recognized the existence of our greatest enemy, the U.S.S.R.

So my question is why does the U.S. not recognize the North Korean government as it does with other enemies, and what does the U.S. gain from this?

Comment: citations please.  Please give evidence that the US only recognises south korea.

Comment: Because the US recognize the government of SK as the only government of whole Korean peninsula. If they recognize NK as a nation then SK would be very concerned. For the same reason US choose not to recognize Taiwan as a nation by itself.

Comment: @user3528438 America's non-recognition of Taiwan differs from its non-recognition of North Korea. As you say, America recognizes South Korea as the rightful government of both North Korea and South Korea. However America does not say that China is the rightful government of Both China and Taiwan. America recognizes China as the government of China. America "acknowledges that Chinese on either side of the Taiwan Strait maintain there is but one China and that Taiwan is a part of China. The United States does not challenge that position." However America does not itself take a position.

Comment: @user3528438 America's position on the China-Taiwan relationship is widely misunderstood; even major newspapers frequently get it wrong.

Comment: @user3528438 on the comparison you made, America recognizes authoritarian China and not democratic Taiwan because China is powerful and it wants China's help. But America recognizes democratic South Korea and not authoritarian North Korea because in the past America feared the Soviet Union and now because America just likes free countries better.

Comment: @Readin You are contradicting with yourself a lot. Also I don't understand what point you are trying to make to me.

Comment: @user3528438 My point is that America's decision on recognizing China and not Taiwan is very different from America's decision to recognize South Korea and not North Korea. It is not true to say "For the same reason US choose not to recognize Taiwan as a nation by itself".

Comment: user3528438 How do I contradict myself?

Comment: @Readin there is but one China and that Taiwan is a part of China

Comment: user3528438 That may be your opinion, but it is not US policy.

Comment: @Readin It's take from one of your quotes.

Comment: @user3528438 but you have taken it out of context.  America recognizes that the Chinese say "there is but one China and Taiwan is part of China", but it doesn't say America agrees. Instead it says America "doesn't challenge" them on it. In other words, America is keeping its opinion a secret because America doesn't want to argue about it. The language was crafted very carefully.

Comment: @Readin If you have a dictionary near by, please look up "acknowledge" or "recognize".

Comment: @Readin  Also there's something interesting known as "1992 Consensus", which is the foundation of PRC's foreign relationship, essentially means "if a political entity want to establish a friendly relationship with PRC government, it must acknowledge one-China/Taiwan is part of China (where such China may or may not be represented by PRC)". US is a significant example that does not recognize PRC as such "one and only China" but still acknowledge the "one China" hence originally I said "Taiwan as a nation by itself". Taiwan is another example that holds "one China being RoC" position.

Comment: @user3528438 "1992 Consensus" was invented by KMT in 2000 to defend their policies regarding China. It isn't Chinese policy and it has nothing to do with American policy. American policy does acknowledge that China says there is one China and that China says Taiwan is part of it.  However American policy stops short of agreeing with China. It's a bit like when you meet someone of another religion. You acknowledge what they believe, but you don't agree and you don't argue about it. America acknowledges China's belief but doesn't challenge it (for the sake of peace).

Comment: We need a moderator to move much of this to chat.

Comment: Perhaps the original questioner meant 'recognition' as in exchanging ambassaors and such rather than the de facto recognition that America extends to governments like NK and countries like Taiwan. If so the questioner should clarify that.

Answer (score 7):

The USA has recognised the DPRK as the [de facto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto) government of the northern portion of the Korean peninsula. In particular, it chose not to veto [UN Security Council Resolution 702](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Security_Council_Resolution_702), which recommended that both North and South Korea both become members of the United Nations. As noted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_recognition):

> A vote by a country in the United Nations in favour of the membership of another country is an implicit recognition of that country by the country so voting, as only states may be members of the UN.

The USA does not maintain [diplomatic relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_relations_of_the_United_States) with North Korea, which is not surprising given the state of hostility between the two governments. The USA also has no diplomatic relations with Iran, Syria or Bhutan.

Comment: this doesn't answer the ***why*** though. As your answer shows they COULD have vetoed the resolution.

Comment: There is no "why" to the original question, because the premise is wrong, because the USA de facto recognises North Korea. Why not diplomatic relations? Because of mutual hostility between the two governments. (Also, the DPRK is reluctant to have external ties with *anyone*.) Why the de facto recognition? Probably in recognition of the simple fact that the DPRK exists and governs North Korea (and had done for more than 40 years at the time Resolution 702 was passed).

Comment: I have always understood diplomatic recognition to include things like exchanging ambassadors and such.  I suspect that is what the original question meant, as opposed to the de facto recognition that America extends to NK. I'll add that as a comment to the question.